# How to disable annoying promt?

Tags: visual-studio

I am in the process of switching over to VS code and was annoyed by the following pop up that rears its ugly head in front of my code while typing.

[image]

How can I get rid of such prompts? Is there a way to get rid of some but not all?

I have downloaded a few extensions but I disabled all of them and this still appeared.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn off tool tips Goto:

> File=>Preference=>Settings

This should take you to

> settings.json

find the following section and configure as follows:

```
// Configures if the built-in HTML language support suggests Angular tags and properties.
"html.suggest.angular1": false,

"html.suggest.ionic": false,

"html.suggest.html5": false,
```

for whatever language you want to turn off set the suggest property to false

To turn off ALL popups, set this property:

```
"editor.parameterHints": false
```